# How to get specific files using fs.readFileSync()

Tags: node.js, audio, coffeescript, atom-editor, fs

I am trying to get only the audio files from a folder that has different file types. Like images, videos etc..

I made a function to filter the results but it only returns me the first audio file I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

coffeescript:

```
@audioFiles = @getAudioFiles()

getAudioFiles: ->

  allFiles = fs.readdirSync(@pathtoMusic.toString())
  musicFiles = Array
  file = 0
  cont = 0

  #-- I also tried with a for loop --#
  #for file of allFiles
  #  fileName = allFiles[file]

  while(file < allFiles.length)
    fileName = allFiles[file++]
    fileExtension = fileName.split('.').pop();

    if(fileExtension is "mp3") or (fileExtension is "MP3")
      musicFiles[cont++] = fileName
    if(fileExtension is "wav") or (fileExtension is "WAV")
      musicFiles[cont++] = fileName
    if(fileExtension is "3gp") or (fileExtension is "3GP")
      musicFiles[cont++] = fileName
    if(fileExtension is "m4a") or (fileExtension is "M4A")
      musicFiles[cont++] = fileName
    if(fileExtension is "webm") or (fileExtension is "WEBM")
      musicFiles[cont++] = fileName

  return musicFiles
```

Is there a way to do it directly?, without needing to create a function or a loop. It would be fantastic. Something like this.

```
fileExtensions = ["mp3","m4a","3gp","wav","webm","etc"...]
@audioFiles = fs.readdirSync(pathToMusic,"fileExtencions")
```

Comment: I resolve the issue. I realize that I was receiving a wrong array length. because I declared the array (musicFiles = Array) without specify the length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're open to using a third-party dependency, consider using [`globby`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/globby):

```
const globby = require('globby');

// Perform a basename-only match if the pattern does not contain
// any slash characters. That is, *.js would be treated as equivalent
// to **/*.js, matching all js files in all directories.
const options = { matchBase: true };
const fileTypes = ['*.mp3', '*.wav', '*.3gp', '*.m4a', '*.webm'];

globby(fileTypes, options).then(paths => {
    console.log(paths);
});
```

Comment: I'm not accustomed to use third-party dependency, but will try. how could I install that dependency in the package I am working on?. I am working on a atom package.

Comment: The dependency can be installed using `npm install globby` or through your project's `package.json`, e.g. `npm install globby -S`

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
getAudioFiles = =>
  fileExtensions = [
    "mp3"
    "m4a"
    "3gp"
    "wav"
    "webm"
    "etc"
  ]
  allFiles = fs.readDirSync @pathtoMusic.toString()
  musicFiles = (file for file in allFiles when file.replace(/.*\./, '') in fileExtensions)
```